# Syntax error in INSERT STATEMENT from c# to Access DB

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

```
 con.Open();
        cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into login (user, password) values ('" +textBox1 .Text + "','" + textBox2 .Text + "');",con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (temp > 0)
        {
           textBox1.Text = null;
            textBox2.Text = null;
            MessageBox.Show("Record Successfuly Added");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Fail to Added");
        }
        con.Close();
```

when i try to insert some of error appear ( syntax error in INSERT STATEMENT )
i'm try different method to values like Parameters or direct
plz !

Comment: I think it is because of the key words like `Login` , `user` and `password`, trying putting square brackets `[]` around them and execute the same query again.

Comment: As @M.Ali has noted, [User is a reserved word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/248738)

Comment: Side Notes: **1)** Use `textBox1.Text = string.Empty` instead of `textBox1.Text = null`. **2)** You can close the connection right after query execution ( `int temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();   con.Close();` ).

Comment: its work now without any error, but when i open the database file i'm doesn't see any info.

Answer (score 2):

- Escape reserved keyword `user`
- use parameterized query
- avoid sql injection
- Make use of disposable objects

Try this approach:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "insert into login ([user], [password]) values (@user, @pass);",
    con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@user", textBox1.Text ));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@pass", textBox1.Text ));

        if (temp > 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
            textBox2.Text = String.Empty;
            MessageBox.Show("Record Successfuly Added");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Fail to Added");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i do?
i'm new user to this site